# Updating state not triggering rerender but I see changes in redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, lodash

I have a reducer that calls a function that modifies one of the arguments and tries to set that back onto the state.

```
case types.MY_ACTION:
    const merged = myMergeFunction(edits, existingValues)
return {
    ...state,
    edits: merged
}
```

When I do this I see the redux store update but no re renders get triggered.

The `myMergeFunction` merges the `edits` onto the `existingValues` and returns the modified existing values. I assume this is somehow causing this not to work since if I merge the changes into a new object or `_.deepClone` the returned object then it works as expected. However this is an extremely large object so cloning it or merging into a new object is too expensive.

```
case types.MY_ACTION:
    const merged = myMergeFunction(edits, existingValues)
return {
    ...state,
    edits: _.cloneDeep(merged)
}
```

What's the best, most performant way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Redux maintainer.  There's a couple issues.

First, when you say that it "merges into `existingValues`, that does suggest that you are *actually* mutating existing state.  That's always a bug - [you must never actually mutate state in Redux](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#do-not-mutate-state).

The second is that you're writing a very outdated style of Redux code.  "Modern Redux" with our official Redux Toolkit package is much easier to learn and use.  And, Redux Toolkit uses Immer inside, so that you *can* write "mutating" syntax in reducers, which gets turned into correct immutable updates.

Please see our Redux docs tutorials, which explain how to use Redux Toolkit:

- https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts